# CSS property customization via PHP sessions?

Tags: php, css, session, properties, customization

I'm pretty new at PHP, I'm currently taking a class in it at a technical school. With that being said, one of our assignments requires us to use sessions to modify 4 CSS properties. body background-color, a:link color, a:hover color, and h1 color. The idea is to basically have 3 pages -1 being a form, with 4 drop-downs, populated with colors, one setting the actual sessions with $_POST data, and the final being the page that actually uses the CSS.

I have it working with cookies but the assignment explicitly says to use sessions as you can see:

The current code i have that sets the sessions is:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['bgColor']= $_POST['bgColor'];
$_SESSION['lColor']=$_POST['lColor'];
$_SESSION['hoverColor']=$_POST['hoverColor'];
$_SESSION['h1Color']=$_POST['h1Color'];
```

On the same page, there is code under that that echo's out the values of the session variables... I can see the colors that are being saved. But, when i try to echo out the CSS like this:

```
 echo "a:link {color: ".$_SESSION['lColor'].";}";
 echo "a:hover {color: ".$_SESSION['hoverColor'].";}";
 echo "body {background-color: ".$_SESSION['bgColor'].";}";
 echo "h1 {color: ".$_SESSION['h1Color']."; text-align:center;}";
```

Its not working, when I check the page source through my web browser, it shows blank properties:

```
 a:link {color: ;}a:hover {color: ;}body {background-color: ;}h1 {color: ; text-align:center;}
```

I would really appreciate any help you guys are willing to give, and please keep in mind that this is my first class in PHP.

Comment: make sure you have session_start on all pages

Answer (score 1):

Are you making sure to start every page that uses the session with session_start();

It must be declared before attempting to call any session vars.

Is your form using method="post" and not get?

Also, you will likely be warned by a lot of SO people to make sure to sanitize everything you get from $_POST. In this case, you are probably safe since it is merely an assignment and not a live site - I assume.

Comment: WOW. I didn't know that i had to have session_start(); on all pages that use sessions. Its working now, thanks! The solution was just the session_start();.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `session_start()` in File3.

Make sure the `PHPSESSID` (or whatever your session variable is called) is being transferred from File2 to File3 via GET in case the user has disabled cookies.

Comment: Thanks! The session_start() was the problem, I can't believe the solution was that easy. You guys are life savers!